# How do we integrate $xe^{x^2}$ in this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, problem-solving

Yeah I did try searching how to integrate $e^{x^2}$ and mostly I stumbled upon how a similar but not this function called Gaussian function $e^{-x^2}$ is un-integrable , now I was given to solve a differential equation $$xe^{x^2}dx + (y^5-1)dy = 0$$ so how do I proceed with the part of integrating $xe^{x^2}dx$ ? I have tried a lot, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So basically you want  to know how to find $\int xe^{x^2}dx$?

Comment: Just if You are interested in integrating $e^{^-x^2}$, using Fubini and polar coordinates gives $(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx)^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx \int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}d\lambda_2= \int_0^{\infty}2\pi r e^{-r^2}dr=\pi$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find $$\int xe^{x^2}dx$$
Set $t=x^2$, $$\frac12\int e^tdt=\frac12e^{x^2}+C$$
Beware, changing the integrand from $xe^{x^2} $ to $e^{x^2}$ makes a hell lot of a difference. Here, you have a $f(g(x))g'(x)$ form, but you changed it to $f(g(x))$ form.

Comment: Well well I realize I just made a fool of myself here..a big fool really...:-[

Comment: Happens, happens. :)